# JAXB - How to unmarshall XML without XSD which contains lists without wrappers

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a complex XML file which I must parse, but I don't have any XSD. The XML looks like this (simplified):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mets:mets ... namespace declaration ommited ... >
      <mets:metsHdr>
          complex mets:metsHdr
      </mets:metsHdr>


      <mets:dmdSec>
          complex mets:dmdSec 1
      </mets:dmdSec>
        ....
      <mets:dmdSec>
          complex mets:dmdSec n
      </mets:dmdSec>


      <mets:fileSec>
          complex mets:fileSec 1
      <mets:fileSec>
        ....
      <mets:fileSec>
          complex mets:fileSec n
      <mets:fileSec>
</mets:mets>
```

There is a header element, not wrapped list of dmdSec and not wrapped list of fileSec.  I tried to read the mets:dmdSec list at first, using these classes:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "mets")
public class Mets {
    @XmlAttribute(name="TYPE")
    private String type;

    @XmlList
    private List<DmdSec> dmdSec;

}


@XmlType
public class DmdSec {

    @XmlAttribute(name="ID")
    private String id;

}
```

But I got this exception:

`Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.DataBindingException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
www.loc.gov.METS.DmdSec maps to a structured XML fragment (AKA complex type), and therefore incompatible with @XmlList.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at private java.util.List www.loc.gov.METS.Mets.dmdSec
        at www.loc.gov.METS.Mets`

```
at javax.xml.bind.JAXB.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just

```
@XmlElement(name="dmdSec")
private List<DmdSec> dmdSec;
```

should do the jobs, also your classes do not match xml, dmdSec does not have id...

You can also use: http://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html#ad-output to generate schema, and generate classes from it or at least seek inspiration from them.

Comment: In reality they do, I just forgot to remove it from the post when I was simplifying the example.